# Mysql join two tables get same field value based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tow tables like this

Table a

```
id  email    firstname  lastname
1   a@a.com   xx         xx      
2   b@b.com   xb         ab
```

Table b

```
  id     email    firstname   lastname
  1      a@a.com    sd          cx       
  2      c@c.com    df          dr
```

i want  to like this

```
  email      firstname     lastname

   a@a.com       xx         xx
   b@b.com       xb         ab
   c@c.com       df         dr
```

any one please help to me.i tried union,distinct not getting my result

Comment: in your table, there is different values of first name and last name for email a@a.com. shouldn't it be corrected?

Comment: Show us the select union that you have tested

Comment: both table  firstname and lastname different.

Comment: i tried below query select email,firstname from tablea where email not in (select distinct(email) from tableb) union select email,firstname from tableb

Comment: my requirement is email,firstname and lastname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT email, firstname, lastname
FROM table_a
UNION
SELECT email, firstname, lastname
FROM table_b
WHERE email NOT IN (SELECT email FROM  table_a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
select email, firstname, lastname from a
union all
select email, firstname, lastname from b
where email not in (select email from a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT email
     , firstname
     , lastname 
  FROM table_a
 UNION
SELECT b.email
     , b.firstname
     , b.lastname 
  FROM table_b b 
  LEFT 
  JOIN table_a a 
    ON a.email = b.email 
 WHERE a.email IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks to all,Working fine